# How to expand div after click and collapse it after another click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an explandable/collapsible element that I created using [Simple-expand](http://sylvain-hamel.github.io/simple-expand/)
 (A jQuery plug-in to expand/collapse elements).

What I want to do is change the css of the element when user clicks on it, expanding it ,and change it again when user clicks on it again ,collapsing it.

Problem is, I don't know how to do that. I know how to change class on click, but how can I change the CSS after the user "unclicked" this tab and it shrinked up?

EDIT: Thanks to George for correcting me on what I wanted to do, to be more clear. I was a bit tired, so I needed it fast. I know this is really bad excuse, but I fully understand and respect you guys, who gave me negative feedback.

Basically what I needed, is:

- There's 6 different divs;
- When you click on one div, it will expand;
- When you click on another div, it will check if ANY OF THESE divs are EXPANDED, if YES - close (collapse) them, and open that div which I clicked on.

For that simple task (it's really simple, it's just me being stupid) I needed to use jQuery `this` statement and a few if's.

I found a solution after 15 mins after publishing this post here and I wanted to delete it, unfortunately, I can't, because it has answers.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me, I appreciate your help.

Cheers!

Comment: Why not adding the css to a special class: .special{} and adding the class dynamically?

Comment: *"Can't post jsFiddle links.."* And there's **a reason** for that. Instead, of working around it, work *with* the way the site is meant to work: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just change it using JavaScript. and unchange it on window.click event

Comment: The "unclick" is not clear to me, did you mean mousedown/mouseup, or click to expand and then click again to collapse?

Comment: Edited the answer, sorry for being so unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a class for when the element is expanded and `toggleClass()` to toggle the class on click

```
$( ".your_element" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "expanded" );
});
```

Comment: @PauliusK.: So, your plan is to just continue to ignore how the site is supposed to work, rather than fixing the question?

Comment: @PauliusK I tried to edit your question so it could be more clear what you wanted.If my answer helped you resolve your problem  you can mark your question as answered.Thanks

Comment: Thanks George, I marked your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FdCm2/)

**CSS**

```
.active {
    background-color: #CC0000;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $("#colormethis").toggleClass('active');
});
```

Use class active than [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) using jQuery
This how you change CSS. So try making it in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use materialize css collapsible [link](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html)